# Install Xerox Phaser 3020 Printer Wifi on 16.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, printing, xerox

I'm having a problem installing my Xerox Phaser 3020 Printer Driver on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. When I use my usb printer cable to connect my notebook to the printer it works fine. But I'm unable to find my printer via Wi-Fi and use it by wi-fi.

Does anyone know a solution for this problem?

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: so for these printers they need to be wirelessly connected to the router; I see on a user guide pdf that there is a wps button: your router should have one too: that allows the two to "talk" .. have you set it up that way? then ubuntu should "see" the printer and offer to config .............

Comment: I fund the solution. The printer have and option to print all the wps configuration if you have the wps button pressed for 10 segs. Then I fund the ip adress of the printer. Next I turned on the printer and the printer was  on the wifi conection of ubuntu desktop. The printer manual have the default password for the wifi conection of the printer. Then when the printer is linked to the PC via WIFI, i was able to find the printer on the ubuntu configuration centre for the printers. Cheers!

Comment: well done; glad it is all working now

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer to help other users in future :)

Comment: @KamoWeasel hey, can you tell me if my answer worked?

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar printer and I had a similar problem.

My printer: Xerox Phaser 3260 Printer Wifi (On Ubuntu 18.10)

Steps to install:

1) After you connect your printer, press the button cancel (the orange one) for about 4 seconds, a page with all the printer's information will be printed.

2) Go to "Wi-fi Direct Information" title and check for **Current SSID** and **Network key.**

3) Log in into the Wifi using the network key provided on the paper.

4) Go to your browser and type the ip address described in "IP Address" just two lines above Current SSId.

5) Find the default admin password of the web console. In my case is "admin:1111" and log in.

6) Go to "properties -> Wifi -> Wifi and click on "Wizard", then you'll be able to configure your wifi connection. (See below)

[image: Webconsole]
7) Configure the printer. In my case was auto detected by Ubuntu.

8) Test the printer.

And you're done!

Answer (score 2):

Try to see if your router has a WPS button. If it has one then follow the steps:

1. Press the green power button on the Phaser printer to wake it up.  Make sure the light bar under the (!) icon is lit solid green.
2. Press and hold the WPS button until the green bar under the (!) icon flashes, then release the button when it begins flashing.
3. While the button is flashing, within two (2) minutes, locate and apply a quick press on the WPS button of your router to activate WPS - PCB mode.
4. If successful, the light bar under the (!) icon will change to a solid blue. The printer will then print a network configuration page. Check in the printed file at the point "Wi-fi network information" if "Status information/Link status" is "Connected". If that is true, you should remove the usb cable if you mounted one between printer and pc/laptop in order to let Ubuntu to discover only the wifi printers.
5. Then go in Ubuntu "Settings" section and identify the "Printers" section. Check if there is an "Add" button for adding a printer, press that and Ubuntu should start scanning and identifing your wifi printer. Add that printer and that's all.